# Scala: Use map function tuples in a subsequent flatMap

Tags: scala, map-function, flatmap

I want to use a tuple of a map function in a subsequent flatMap.

Like this:

```
val list = orders.map(ord => (ord.prod.tasks, ord.quantity))
                 .zipWithIndex flatMap {
                   case (variable, index) =>
                     createSchedules(variable._1.size * variable._2, ord, null)
                 }
```

Is there a way in which I can use it or do you think that I have to change the way that I'm thinking about the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to use a tuple of a map function in a subsequent flatMap.

Here's a working example of using tuples in a subsequent flatMap

```
val input = List("a", "b", "c")
val list = input.map(i => (i + "A", i + "B")).zipWithIndex flatMap{ case (variable, index)=> variable._1 + variable._2}
```

> Issue with original code

```
val list = orders.map(ord => (ord.prod.tasks, ord.quantity)).zipWithIndex flatMap{case (variable, index)=>createSchedules(variable._1.size * variable._2, ord, null)}
```

One issue is that **ord** is out of scope in the 'createSchedules' call.

**ord** will only be visible in the initial 'orders.map' scope.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, judging from the parameters that you're passing to `createSchedules`, it looks as if that function can be simplified to (I'm ignoring the `null` parameter for now):

```
def createSchedules(order: Order): List[Schedule] = {
  val num = order.prod.tasks.size * order.quantity
  // do stuff
}
```

Also, the initial `map` is unnecessary. `list` can be simplified to:

```
val list = orders.zipWithIndex
                 .flatMap {
                   case (order, index) =>
                     createSchedules(order)
                 }
```

It's unclear what you need the `index` for, though.